# How to Analyze logs from multiple sources in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have started working on ELK recently and have a doubt regarding handling of multiple types of logs.
I have two sets of logs on my server that I want to analyse, one from my android application and the other from my website. I have successfully transferred logs from this server via filebeat to the ELK server.
I have created two filters for either types of logs and have successfully imported these logs into logstash and then Kibana.

This link helped do the above stuff.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7

The above link directs to use the logs in the filebeat index in Kibana and start analysing(I successfully did for one type of logs). But the problem that I am facing is that since both these logs are very different, they need to be analysed differently. How do I do this in Kibana. Should I create multiple filebeat indexes there and import them, or should it be just one single index, or some other way. I am not very clear on this(could not find much documentation), hence would request to please help and guide me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch organizes by index and type.  Elastic used to compare these to SQL concepts, but now offers a [new explanation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type).

Since you say that the logs are very different, Elastic is saying that you should use different indexes.

In Kibana, the visualization is tied to an index.  If you had one panel from each index, you can show them both on the same dashboard.

Comment: Alain, I have already created a Filebeat index that is accepting both types of logs. What I understand is that the difference in handling these logs should happen in the logstash filter files, where I will have to apply different filters to both sets of logs. So now my query is how do I create two different filebeat indexes and configure each to handle particular type of log.Due to my limited knowledge on ELK, I may be asking rookie question here, but please let me know this in detail.

Comment: The filebeat index that I created by following the above link downloaded the following template.  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thisismitch/3429023e8438cc25b86c/raw/d8c479e2a1adcea8b1fe86570e42abab0f10f364/filebeat-index-template.json

Comment: The index that logstash uses when talking to elasticsearch is defined in the elasticsearch output{} stanza.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alain.  Please tell me how do I create two different filebeat indexes and configure each to handle particular type of log

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Alain. I was finally able to create multiple indices. Thanks for the help in earlier comments.